# Checkbox field should be visible to all profiles only if it is checked by the system admin can we do that?

Tags: checkbox

I have this checkbox which is visible to everyone right now , I want that field to be visible only when System admin checks the box. Can I do that ? but The other profiles are editing that page then they should not see that check box

Please help out

Thanks
Priya

Comment: you can remove the field level access to all the profiles, except system admin profile.  Navigation Go to the object manager --> select object --> Fields & relationships --> open the respective checkbox field --> click on Set Field level Security --> remove the visible access to all the profiles except system admin.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your query, you want the checkbox to be *editable by System Admin only*  and when System Admin checks it, it should be *visible to all users as **Read Only***

Provide Read Only access to all profiles and Edit access to System Admin

Use **Dynamic Forms** in the record page (supports Lightning only) to show/hide the field based on your required conditions. Please follow below link for details

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_migrate.htm&type=5

---

---Use Something like below in Dynamic Form Field Visibility

[image]

Comment: Hello , This was really helpful article, But it is not allowing me check the filters profile level, But user level, permission and record level its giving me options.Please let me know if I am wrong. I wanted to control profile so that anyone added to that profile will have the same effect.

Comment: You can use User > Profile. I have Edited My Answer to add a sample logic screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

You can remove the field level access to all the profiles, except system admin profile.

Lightning Navigation:

Go to the object manager --> select **object** --> **Fields & relationships** --> open the respective checkbox field --> click on **Set Field level Security** button-->  remove the visible access to all the profiles except system admin and save.

Classic Navigation:

Setup --> **Build**--> **create** --> select **objects** --> click on the respective object --> go to the **Custom Fields & Relationships** section --> open the respective checkbox field --> click on **Set Field level Security** button-->  remove the visible access to all the profiles except system admin and save.

Comment: Thank you ! This is only one part the second part is to make the field visible when the check box is checked by system admin